# Breaking up a Path to contours

Tags: android, path

I'm trying to break down a complex Path in Android into its subcontours.
Currently I came up with this code:

```
public static ArrayList<Path> splitToContours(Path path) {
ArrayList<Path> list = new ArrayList<Path>();
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path, true);
float segment = 0;
Path tempPath;
do {
    tempPath = new Path();
    tempPath.rewind();
    pm.getSegment(segment, segment + pm.getLength(), tempPath, true);
    segment += pm.getLength();
    tempPath.close();
    list.add(tempPath);
} while (pm.nextContour());
return list;
}
```

However it seems to me that the last point in a contour also starts the next contour.
Can anyone help me out? Perhaps there's a simpler, more elegant way to do this? I've been banging my head against the wall for the last two weeks about that and I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: Thanks for this example, it helped me arrive at a solution. I found that in `pm.getSegment()` the first two parameters are relative to the current contour rather than absolute offsets. So you don't need the `segment` variable, just call `pm.getSegment(0, pm.getLength(), tempPath, true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your exact problem is, but I use something like this to create a drawing style animation. You seem to be on the right track, maybe don't close the paths?

```
 List<Path> segmentPath(Path path, float segmentLength, float scale,
            float dx, float dy) {
        PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path, false);
        float length = pm.getLength();

        float start = 0;
        float delta = segmentLength;

        List<Path> segments = new ArrayList<Path>();
        while (start <= length) {
            float end = start + delta;
            if (end > length) {
                end = length;
            }

            Path segment = new Path();
            pm.getSegment(start, end, segment, true);

            segments.add(segment);
            start += delta;
        }

        return segments;
    }
```