# Android Suggest a better way to break Android Graphics Path objects into parts

Tags: android, graphics

I am working on an Android Drawing app. I am working with List of Path objects and Paint objects.

There is an eraser functionality, this eraser need to break the path (intersecting path with it) in parts.

Say I have path P, now, I have drawn eraser on P, then P will be broken into P1 & P2. Again, If I do erase P1, it should be broken into P11 & P12.

I wanted to  know about is there any better way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done myself, as I did not got any answers from Stack Overflow experts.

Got some hint from : [Breaking up a Path to contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785177/breaking-up-a-path-to-contours)
and rest done as per the requirement.